# Selenium font family is not displayed in full on IE 8

Tags: html, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

I have an automation test suit in which we verify the font family of elements.The problem is that for the elements that are into a table like `<td><label class="class1">Label 1</label></td>` the font-family is truncated.

The elements have font style: `Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif` but selenium function `element.GetCssValue("fontFamily")` for elements that in a table return only `Arial` if the element is not included in a HTML table we got all 3 font style.

This issues reproduce only on Selenium if I inspect the element I see all 3 font-family styles.

How can I get all 3 font family style in  this situation?

Comment: Check the table CSS property as well, it may override the content CSS.

Comment: @Karthikeyan Thank you for your quick reply. Yes, actually the problem is the inheritance, and It doesn't need to be a table it can be anything like <div> or <span>. Thank you again. And for other that have this error you can get the parent with element.FindElement(By.XPath("..")) <- C# scode